# Apple's Mail.App, how to reply with full headers?

Tags: apple-mail, microsoft-outlook-2011

In Apple's Mail.App, can you reply with full headers?

For example, in Outlook (and most other mail software), replying will show you something like:

```
From: John Doe <john@foo.com>
Date: Monday, July 23, 2013 9:34 AM
To: Jane Doe <jane@foo.com>
Cc: Bob <bob@foo.com>
Subject: RE: Test Message
```

Mail.app simply says the following - which omits the import details of who was cc'd etc:

```
On Jul 23, 2012, at 9:34 AM, "John Doe" <john@foo.com> wrote:
```

I would much prefer Mail.app over Outlook 2011, but I'm trapped without the ability to maintain the thread of recipients in replies.

Surely there's some way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... I've got a workable solution:

Longtime Mail.app users may remember the "ReplyWithHeaders" plugin that was abandoned years ago. Well, it's been resurrected and then abandoned again, but at the time of this writing works for OS X 10.8.4 and can be obtained here:
https://github.com/jschroth/ReplyWithHeaders

And if you've got a version of "ReplyWithHeaders" that doesn't work, it too can likely be be made to work simply by changing the UUID's per the instructions here: http://code2k.net/blog/2010-05-16/

From all my searching and testing, this appears to be the best solution available at this time.

Comment: ReplyWithHeader plugin development back on track. Plugin is compatible with Lion and Mountain Lion (up to Mail 6.6). [Download plugin from MacUpdate.com](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/49256/replywithheader)